# What is the "solve-the-equation" approach/method/approximation?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, estimators

I've seen a number of references to a "solve-the-equation" approach (or method, etc) to choose a kernel density estimation (KDE) bandwidth, but different papers use different citations, and none of them seem to give a pedagogical explanation for this, or the origin of the term.

For example one paper refers to [Sheather & Jones 1991](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2345597?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) but that paper doesn't use this phrase at all.  Similarly for the references in the [Wikipedia KDE page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#A_rule-of-thumb_bandwidth_estimator) which also uses the term.

Comment: Simon Sheather and Chris Jones use the term "plug in" -- is that what you mean by "solve-the-equation"? (e.g. see top of page 685 of your ref) which term they appear to attribute to Park and Marron (1990) but list a history of papers developing the ideas leading up to that.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b, I'm not sure --- I don't know what this term is supposed to mean, so I can't really compare it to "plug in"... unfortunately.